# Multiple copies of files on SD card

Tags: sony-xperia

I use Sony Xperia C1505 which I got three years ago. The phone had been repaired multiple times because od Jack not working and system crash but everything seemed fine since the last repair which had been six months ago.
The problem is that every time I connect phone to pc using USB cable, some files duplicate but I can´t delete any of them (the phone says "Failed to delete file")
All copies of music are working though. Some of photos are "broken files" but when I reload the SD card, everything is fine.
My gallery now has more that 4K of pics instead of 1K. It still ceeps multiplying the files everytime I connect the phone.
[image: This is what happened]

I tried restarting phone several times, moved everything from SD card to PC and deleted everything but the problem stil persists...
I am scared to delete the copies because I don´t want to lose any of them
P.S.: I apologize for my english, it is my third language

Comment: Can you check the details of those duplicates, if they really point to the same directory? I vaguely remember a similar issue where the media scanner was going nuts and didn't see that `/sdcard` was just a symbolic link to `/storage/sdcard0`, thus showing the same file twice (one for `/sdcard` and one for `/storage/sdcard0`). Since Lollipop and multi-user, there are now additional symlinks pointing to the same source, which might explain the multiple copies – or, if the scanner got really nuts, it might even include the thumbnails separately.

Comment: Yes, every single copy is in the same folder and even has the same name, it doesn´t even behave like a copy. When I tried selecting them, if I selected one copy it said "1 selected" but if i did select the another copy of the same it said "0 selected"
I deleted one copy and it was fine but really, deleting three thousands of pictures...

Comment: OK, looks like the media scanner messed up its database. I'd try to clear the media storage (see [the middle of this page](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr/Tutorials/How-To-Refresh-Android-Media-Cache): go to *Settings › Apps › All,* find "Media Storage", chose "clear data"), then reboot (on device startup, the [media scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) will be triggered to run, and should – this time cleanly – build up it's database). Note: If you've customized ringtones/notification sounds, you might need to redo that afterwards as the association might be lost.

Comment: Glad this solved it! So I will make it a complete answer. Please check that (in a few minutes) and mark it "accepted" (by ticking the green check-mark next to it), so other users with the same issue can identify it as solution. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the media scanner messed up its database. I recommend to:

1. clear the media storage (see [the middle of this page](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr/Tutorials/How-To-Refresh-Android-Media-Cache) for details with screenshots):

   1. go to *Settings › Apps › All*
   2. find "Media Storage" and tap the entry once to open the app details
   3. chose "clear data" (to empty the media scanner's database)
2. reboot

On device startup, the [media scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) will be triggered to run, and should – this time cleanly – build up it's database.

**Note:** If you've customized ringtones/notification/alarm sounds, you might need to redo that afterwards as the association might be lost.²

---

<sup>**²** Applications identify those sounds by an ID, not by directory and file name. With the new buildup database, those IDs no longer match.</sup>